gfm-mode does not highlight tsx code blocks
I'm using gfm-mode from markdown-mode.
For typescript code blocks that look like the following:
```typescript
const i: number;
```

gfm-mode can syntax highlight them properly. However, it doesn't highlight tsx code blocks:
```tsx
const i: number;
```

What should I do here?
Additional context:
The following evaluates to t in my Emacs instance.
(treesit-language-available-p (intern "tsx"))

This is different from Github-flavored markdown mode: syntax highlight code blocks, as I'm asking about syntax highlighting for code blocks with specific languages.
